# Debug React Microservice Application with webpack and tailor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, webpack, microservices

I have a microservice application created with react and tailored with tailor. My backend is simulated with node.js at the moment.

Now I try to debug without ending up in the bundle.js but in the actual javascript file.

I followed these instruction (using phpstorm instead):
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-react-apps/

I use devtool: 'source-map' in the webpack.config.js and configured a Javascript Debug Job, where I added the remote URL.

Everything seems to work, when I set a breakpoint in the microservice, that is rendered first by tailor.

But a breakpoint in another service is never hit. The source mapping is configured in every microservice webpack.config.js.
Even in the webpack://. folder, only the code from the firstly loaded microservice is shown.

I figured, that I could run every microservice standalone and debug it this way. But since service 1 might trigger an event in service 2, debugging the wohle application is more suitable.

Has anyone an idea, how to debug such an application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

I first excluded every build folder of every microservice via "settings" -> "directories" like described here:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/09/debugging-webpack-applications-in-webstorm/
Additionally I marked every src folder as Source Folder in the settings, too.

In the JavaScript Debug job, I then mapped every src folder by assigning the Remote URL "webpack:///src" (which is actually not necessary with Webstorm 2017+ and having only one src folder). At last I assigned the Remote URL "http://myapp.com" to the root folder.

Now it looks like this:

[Remote URLs of local files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66w7z.png)

That's all. When I run the Debug Job and have multiple breakpoints in different services, I can debug directly in the IDE and in the corresponding js file (instead of the bundle.js).